# Map attributes over to object using an hash

Tags: ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

So I have two model objects who hold similar data yet have different attribute names for them. I'll simplify the list for brevity and clarity. I want to actually make a temporary object with the info, compare the objects, and then update one if some of the data has changed. I'm open to suggestions about how to better accomplish this (please keep in mind that there are a lot more attributes then I'm showing)

**Member** object has the attributes **employeenumber, employeefirstname and employeelastname**

**Censusitem** object has the attributes **employee_id, employee_fn, employee_ln**

I have a has with the fields mapped over that I thought would simplify this:

```
maps={
  employeenumber: :employee_id,
  employeefirstname: :employee_fn,
  employeelastname: :employee_ln
}
```

I thought I could then loop them and assign them somehow, but I'm obviously not even close:

```
def clean_member(censusitem, maps)
    tempmember=Member.new
    maps.each do |mname,ciname|
      tempmember.i[o]=censusitem.i[1]
    end
  return tempmember
end
```

Feel like I'm missing something big, which is very normal for me;-) Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this should work:

```
def clean_member(censusitem, maps)
    tempmember=Member.new
    maps.each do |mname,ciname|
      tempmember.send("#{mname}=", censusitem.send(ciname))
    end
  return tempmember
end
```